# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).error CS0433, C#, XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, assemblies, xmlserializer

I am generating the dynamic assemblies at run time. That dynamic assembly has few classes which are already defined in the code in some another assembly. The name space of common class is same in both assemblies.

Now when I am using `XmlSerializer` its throwing the ambiguity exception.

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0433: The type AppName.Common.Objects.Volatility' exists in both 'AppName.Data.Common.dll' and 'AppName\bin\Debug\Volatility.dll'
```

Any idea on this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Dheeraj Verma

Comment: You seem to have identified the problem. You can't have the classes defined as they are, because of the conflict. Can you change the name of the namespace or the class in either assembly?

Comment: actually code is very tightly coupled. i can't do that.. can we enhance XmlSerializer such that when it is going to create the empty object it can refer to only one assembly.

Comment: ...you would have this problem at compile time, were this compiled code. As it is - I don't know of any way to trick the XmlSerializer into *not* seeing a linked .dll.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you have a class called `Volatility` in namespace `AppName.Common.Objects` that is present on the interface of two dlls.

One would appear to be a copied and referenced `volatility.dll` in the debug output directory and one that has been autogenerated `AppName.Data.Common.dll`.

I suspect that you'll find Volatile class in Common class and it's containing dll, but also within volatility.dll.

**edit**

I think that your only route here is to explicitly declare the object type that you're passing to the XMLSerializer. You may need to test for object type and run through a switch statement to call the XMLSerializer with the correct object type.

Comment: yes this is the problem. But how could i resolve it? I cannot change the code much as its really complicated. Can i enhance XmlSerializer such that when it is going to create the empty object it can refer to only one assembly.

Comment: You'll need to explicitly declare the type.